# How to achieve the correct joins in my PostgreSQL query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am facing troubles with generating a query, as I am new to this.

I have 4 tables: movies, ratings, principals and actors

Movies table consists of: tconst(a key), titles, start year
ratings table consists of: tconst(a key), average rating, number of voters
actors table consists of: actors name, birth year, death year, nconst(a key)
principals table is a junction table : nconst, tconst

I would like to create a table that will be able to have one column being the year of a movie, the second column being all the movies released in that year, and the third column having all actors born after that year

I used the query

```
SELECT 
    movies.start_year, 
    array_agg(DISTINCT(actors.name)) AS actors_born_after, 
    array_agg(movies.title) AS movies_title, 
    array_agg(DISTINCT(actors.birth_year)) 
FROM movies 
INNER JOIN principals on movies.tconst=principals.tconst 
INNER JOIN actors on principals.nconst=actors.nconst 
WHERE actors.birth_year > movies.start_year 
GROUP BY movies.start_year 
limit 5;
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `distinct` is **not**  a function. `distinct(actors.name)` and `distinct actors.name` are the same thing

Comment: I've added a useful title. Also, note that "it's not working" is [not a useful fault report](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT 
    movies.start_year, 
    movies_agg.movies_title, 
    array_agg(DISTINCT(actors.name)) actors_born_after -- Get list of actors
FROM movies
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT start_year, array_agg(DISTINCT(title)) AS movies_title -- Get all movies per each year
    FROM movies a
    GROUP BY start_year
) AS movies_agg ON movies.start_year = movies_agg.start_year -- Get list of movies from same year
LEFT JOIN actors ON actors.birth_year > movies.start_year -- Get all actors born after movie start_year
GROUP BY movies.start_year, movies_agg.movie_titles
```

This should give you:

- year of the movie
- all movies released in that year
- all actors born after that year

I haven't tested it, so you may have some syntax errors.  Give it a try and let me know.

Comment: Hi ravioli, thank you! I just ran the code but it did not work. The error is that movies.agg does not exist. I was wondering if I should make use of the junction table, which consists of foreign keys from actors table and movies table. If not, there is no way we can JOIN the movies to the actors.

Comment: actors table : 
nconst(key), actors name, birth year

movies table:
tconst(key), movies title, movie year

principals table:
nconst,tconst

Comment: Can you post the exact SQL you used and the full error message?
  `movies_agg` is a derived table, so you should be able to reference it by its alias.

Comment: If you wanted to get all the actors for a given movie, then yes, you'd need to use your `principals` table.  But in your question, you just said you want "all movies released in that year."  So, I assumed you were looking for something different.

Comment: yes my bad, you understood what I needed to get correctly! I just ran the code, I fixed a bit of the syntax but now the problem is that it does not return an error message nor a result.

Comment: Hmm...if you ran it as above, then the only way to not get any rows is if your `movies` table is empty, since it's all `LEFT JOIN`s.  Can you post the SQL as you executed it?  And how are you running the query, via `psql`?

Comment: I am using Postgres psql 
the command that I ran is:
    SELECT movies.start_year, 
        movies_agg.movies_title, 
        array_agg(DISTINCT(actors.name)) actors_born_after 
    FROM movies
    LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT start_year, array_agg(DISTINCT(title)) AS movies_title 
    FROM movies a
    GROUP BY start_year)
    AS movies_agg ON movies.start_year = movies_agg.start_year
    LEFT JOIN actors ON actors.birth_year > movies.start_year
    GROUP BY movies.start_year, movies_agg.movies_title

Comment: Interesting.  And what happens when you do `select * from movies;` -- do you get any rows?

Comment: If you do, then try commenting out the aggregate parts of the query and see if that makes any difference: `SELECT 
 movies.start_year
 ,movies_agg.movies_title
-- , array_agg(DISTINCT(actors.name)) actors_born_after 
FROM movies 
LEFT JOIN (
 SELECT
  start_year,
  array_agg(DISTINCT(title)) AS movies_title 
 FROM movies a 
 GROUP BY start_year
) AS movies_agg ON movies.start_year = movies_agg.start_year 
LEFT JOIN actors ON actors.birth_year > movies.start_year 
--GROUP BY movies.start_year, movies_agg.movies_title`